# Get array elements space separated instead of comma separated

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have a table `"Health"` in PostgreSQL with two columns

```
Health_id   integer
health_data double precision[]
```

Example data:

```
Health_id  health_data
1          {1,2.1,3.2,8.1,9.0}
```

I want to select the array `health_data` from `Health` where `health_id = ?`, but I am getting the array with commas:

```
{1,2.1,3.2,8.1,9.0}
```

How can I get the array with spaces instead of commas, Like this:

```
{1 2.1 3.2 8.1 9.0}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default text representation of arrays has commas to separate elements.
Use [**`array_to_string()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) to produce the text representation you desire (actual type `text`):

```
SELECT array_to_string(health_data, ' ') AS health_data_with_spaces
FROM   "Health";
```

If you want the surrounding `{}`, add them manually:

```
SELECT '{' || array_to_string(health_data, ' ') || '}' AS health_data_with_spaces
FROM   "Health";
```

Answer (score 0):

array_to_string should do it.

```
select '{' || array_to_string(array[1,2.1,3.2,8.1,9.0], ' ') || '}';
      ?column?       
---------------------
 {1 2.1 3.2 8.1 9.0}
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-array.html